# How to execute local bash code from VSCode extension

Tags: javascript, bash, typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am creating an extension for simple git commands, and when a user enters a command in the Command Palette, like `Init`, I want to call `git init` on their current directory.

Unfortunately, there is no documentation on executing code locally with the VSCode extensions API. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, by using [child_process.spawn](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v11.x/docs/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options). I have used it [in my extension to run a Java jar](https://github.com/mike-lischke/vscode-antlr4/blob/master/src/backend/SourceContext.ts#L932). The core of the execution is shown here:

```
let spawnOptions = { cwd: options.baseDir ? options.baseDir : undefined };
let java = child_process.spawn("java", parameters, spawnOptions);

let buffer = "";
java.stderr.on("data", (data) => {
    let text = data.toString();
    if (text.startsWith("Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS:")) {
        let endOfInfo = text.indexOf("\n");
        if (endOfInfo == -1) {
            text = "";
        } else {
            text = text.substr(endOfInfo + 1, text.length);
        }
    }

    if (text.length > 0) {
        buffer += "\n" + text;
    }
});

java.on("close", (code) => {
    // Handle the result + errors (i.e. the text in "buffer") here.
}
```